# retrieve Artifact item as a property

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm trying to retrieve artifact items  in maven-dependecy-plugin by name as a property to write its value in my war manifest file .
I need something like `${project.artifactItems["name"].value}` to retrieve my values without having to read each jar manifest file as a stream programmaticaly.

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>copy-installed</id>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>copy</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <artifactItems>
        <artifactItem>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>prj-applet</artifactId>
          <version>${test.project.version}</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </artifactItem>
        <artifactItem>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>prj-pdf-render-applet</artifactId>
          <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
          <version>${test.project.version}</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </artifactItem>
      </artifactItems>
```

I need to insert each retrieved value in my manifest file using the war plugin :

```xml
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<warName>test</warName>
  <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
   <!-- <warName>test</warName> -->
  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  <archive>
    <manifestEntries>

      <applicationVersion>${pom.version}</applicationVersion>
      <applicationBuildTimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</applicationBuildTimestamp>
    </manifestEntries>
  </archive>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some-groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifactid</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

you can get your dependency with ${maven.dependency.some-groupid.some-artifactid.jar.path}